# Separate sub-figures!

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision

Any idea on separating multi-panel figures?[image]

There are 2 different sub-figures connected each other.

Thanks!

Comment: In your example above, the sub-images each take up half the total image. Will the sub-images always take up a certain fraction of the image?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, it's straightforward. Let's consider [a more general case, involving a grid](http://englishwalle.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/9-image-grid-no-logo1.jpg):

[image: Complex image panel]

First run [ridge detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ridge_detection), [box blurring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_blur), then [line detection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_detection):

[image: First run ridge detection, and box blurring]

The purpose of this preprocessing is to make line detection more successful. Finally, partition the image vertically (only first partition shown):

[image: First horizontal partition]

then horizontally:

[image: The finished result]

In Mathematica it can be done as follows:

```
img = Import["http://englishwalle.files.wordpress.com/2013/08/9-image-grid-no-logo1.jpg"]
{W, H} = ImageDimensions[img]
edges = ImageConvolve[Binarize@RidgeFilter[img, 0.001], BoxMatrix[2]]
lines = ImageLines[edges, 2, 0.1]
hlines = Select[lines, Norm[#[[1]] - #[[2]]] == W &]
offsets = Flatten@{0, #[[1 , 2]] & /@ hlines, ImageDimensions[img][[2]]}
hparts = Partition[H - # & /@ offsets // Sort, 2, 1]
vsections = ImageTake[img, #] & /@ hparts

(* Part 2 *)
hmask = ImageAdjust[ImageAdjust@RidgeFilter[Blur[#, {100, 0}], 5], 1] & /@ vsections
lines = ImageLines[#, 0.075, 0.25] & /@ hmask
vlines = #[[1, 1]] & /@ # & /@ lines
vlinesUnique = W*DeleteDuplicates@MeanShift[#, 1] & /@ vlines/W
vparts = Partition[Flatten[{0, Sort@#, W}], 2, 1] & /@ vlines_uniq
hsections = Outer[ImageTake, {#[[1]]}, {{0, W}}, #[[2]], 1] & /@ Transpose[{vsections, vparts}]
```

I leave it to you to translate this into your language of choice.

edit: With your image, I had better results with a derivative filter than a ridge filter (though that worked too, but the seam was not exactly at the right place). This is what directional blurring and derivative filtering (`hmask = DerivativeFilter[Blur[img, {100, 0}], {0, 1}]`) looks like on your image:

[image: After vertical blurring]

[image: After derivative filtering]

Line detection works trivially after this.

Comment: Thanks! We have tried in a similar way. It does not show up lines sometimes. Those cases are really difficult. Can you really find vertical line between two images, I have provided? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, I can, but if you want to deploy a system like this in production that's robust enough to work with a wide variety of cases, you'll have to throw more machine learning at it. I think this is as far as you can go with bare image processing. (Actually, even that's not true; my original solution uses clustering through the `MeanShift` function.)